# Comparing an array with an exact value and an approximate value in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Python matrix array for example like this one:

```
a = array([[0, 2, 1, 1.4142, 4, 7],
       [3, 0, 1.4142, 9, 2, 0],
       [1.4142, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3]])
```

I want to convert all the elements of this array being different to 1 or different to sqrt(2) (1.4142) to 0. That is:

```
a = array([[0, 0, 1, 1.4142, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1.4142, 0, 0, 0],
           [1.4142, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

I have tried this

```
a[(a != 1).any() or not (np.isclose(a, np.sqrt(2))).any()] = 0
```

and some variations but I can't make it to work. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use masking -

```
m1 = np.isclose(a,1) # use a==1 for exact matches
m2 = np.isclose(a,np.sqrt(2))
a[~(m1 | m2)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
np.where((a == 1.4142), a, a == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to check sum and product of elements for both arrays? correct if I am wrong this should work for positive numbers.